# Do we have to have mandatory field in content Schema?

Tags: 2013-sp1, content-manager, schema

Do we have to have at least ONE mandatory field in content Schema?

Comment: What's the rationale for the question? Did you not try and create a schema with only optional fields? Are you also expecting to create 'null' components or something? what for?

Comment: I'm curious if this was a situation where Thakur's colleague said you _must_ have a mandatory field and we're about to resolve the "discussion." :-) But don't leave us in suspense!

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT - I have misread the question initially**

No, you don't. You could have them all optional.

My original answer is below, it might be useful to someone if he misreads it as I have originally :)

**OLD ANSWER - Answer to the question 'do you need to have at least one content field in a Schema'.**

No, you don't have to. It's very much possible to have a Schema with just Metadata fields, I have created a fair amount during the years and there is one example in the DXA example even.

It is even possible to have no fields at all. Now does such a Schema even make sense? Well in some cases yes, most frequently for some dummy Components to run templating code, page linking or something similar, not for content.